# AccountManager peekAuthToken returning null value

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have an auth token saved into the AccountManager, however, when I do peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType) it is returning me null. My caller uid is same and the account does exists in the Account Manager. I also have the android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS in my Manifest file.

Comment: I had the same problem and it took me days to notice that `authTokenType` passed to `AccountManager.setAuthToken` and `AccountManager.peekAuthToken` were not matching, consequently returning always `null`.

Answer (score 1):

peekAuthToken will return null if the account does not exist or token not in cache. When we call to get token from AccountManager (like blockingGetAuthToken) it will get token from cache and not call getAuthToken function in AccountAuthenticator. And because token not in cache so that peekAuthToken return null.

So in this case, call peekAuthToken will pointless.

And in case you want run peekAuthToken, to manually check something before return token, try to add **android:customTokens="true"** in **account-authenticator** xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible scenarios where [`AccountManager.peekAuthToken`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) will return `null`:

- No [`account`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html) stored in the [account manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) matches the provided one.
- No account stored in the account manager has the given `authTokenType`.
- The provided account exists, but its `authTokenType` mismatches the one given.
- *Finally*, no authentication token is cached for the provided (`account`, `authTokenType`) pair.

For authenticators where `android:customToken=true`, you should provide a non-negative [`KEY_CUSTOM_TOKEN_EXPIRY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#KEY_CUSTOM_TOKEN_EXPIRY) `long` value containing the expiration time in milliseconds.

If `android:customTokens=false`, tokens are cached indefinitely until some client calls [`invalidateAuthToken`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)